# Replace file header containing escape characters

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr, vignette

I created a vignette for a package with following header:

```
---
title: "My package vignette"
output: rmarkdown::html_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{MyPackage}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

However, vignette format [doesn't allow full functionalities allowed by html_document](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/650#issuecomment-199887449).

I would like to automatically change the YAML header in order to have the ability to knit the vignette in full html_document format (with options like `toc_float: true`)

I'm trying to read the `.Rmd` file with `ReadLines` and replace the header using `gsub`, but I'm struggling with escape characters / regex:

```
content <- readLines('vignettes/MyPackage.Rmd',encoding = 'UTF-8')

vignette_header <- "output: rmarkdown::html_document
vignette: >
  %\\VignetteIndexEntry{MyPackage}
  %\\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}"

normal_header <- 
'output:
  html_document:
    toc_float: true'  

gsub(vignette_header,normal_header,content )
Error in gsub(vignette_header, normal_header, content) : 
  regular expression 'output: rmarkdown::html_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{ALPSYSparams}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}' incorrect, because of 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

Thanks for your suggestions, alternative methods to modify a file header with escape characters welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying header, as a workaround I made two Rmarkdown files with different headers, and used `child` chunck option to insert the same Markdown body:

1. Vignette :

````
---
title: "My package vignette"
output: rmarkdown::html_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{MyPackage}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r child=here::here('data/MyPackageVignetteBody.Rmd')}

```
````

2. Fully featured Markdown :

````
---
title: "My package fully featured Markdown"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

```{r child=here::here('data/MyPackageVignetteBody.Rmd')}

```
````